# How can I get First date and Last date of month in fscalender in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, fscalendar

How can I get month calendar start and end date?

From the screenshot, I need to get 1 aug 2017 and 31 aug 2017 in fscalender?

when i scroll then this method call but everytime get current date

```
- (void)calendarCurrentPageDidChange:(FSCalendar *)calendar;
{

}
```

thanks!

[image]

Comment: got answer......................

Comment: Have you got the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get First date

```
 - (void)calendarCurrentPageDidChange:(FSCalendar *)calendar;
    {
        NSLog(@"did change to page %@",[self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:calendar.currentPage]);

    }
```

Comment: Actually, I want to take the first and last date of the month. And I got the first date but I am stuck on the last date so if you have found any solution for the last date of the month then can you please help me in that.

Answer (score 1):

The `FSCalendar` property `currentPage` returns the start date of currently showing page - this is the first day of the month or week depending on whether you are showing a month or week.

Then use `NSCalendar` methods to find the last day of the month or week that starts with `currentPage`. There are a number of ways to do this; e.g. add an `NSDateComponents` value or use one of the "next" methods such as `nextDateAfterDate:matchingUnit:value:options:`.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can use these two `NSDate` category methods for your need:

```
- (NSDate *)startDateOfMonth {
    NSCalendar *current = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *startOfDay = [current startOfDayForDate:self];
    NSDateComponents *components = [current components:(NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear) fromDate:startOfDay];
    NSDate *startOfMonth = [current dateFromComponents:components];
    return startOfMonth;
}

- (NSDate *)endDateOfMonth {
    NSCalendar *current = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    components.month = 1;
    components.day = -1;
    NSDate *endOfMonth = [current dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:[self startDateOfMonth] options:NSCalendarSearchBackwards];
    return endOfMonth;
}
```

You need to convert the date from your `FSCalendar` to `NSDate`:

```
- (void)calendarCurrentPageDidChange:(FSCalendar *)calendar {
    NSDate *date = ... //Conversion goes here

    NSDate *startDateOfMonth = [date startDateOfMonth];
    NSDate *endDateOfMonth = [date endDateOfMonth];

    // convert back if you need to
}
```

Comment: NSDate *date = ... //Conversion goes here ? Which date i Pass

Comment: How did you get current date?

Comment: it's load automatically current month

Comment: Your requirement isn't quite clear. Okay, tell me why are you using `FSCalendar`?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)calendarCurrentPageDidChange:(FSCalendar *)calendar{
    [self.calendar selectDate:[self.calendar.currentPage fs_firstDayOfMonth]];
    [self.calendar selectDate:[self.calendar.currentPage fs_lastDayOfMonth]];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You get First and Last date of Current Month by yourself. No need to get it from FSCalendar. For this see below code.

```
NDDate *currentDate = //Pass date which you get
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *comp = [gregorian components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay ) fromDate:currentDate];
[comp setMonth:[comp month]];
[comp setDay:1];
NSDate *firstDayDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comp];
[comp setMonth:[comp month]+1];
[comp setDay:0];
NSDate *lastDayDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comp];

NSLog(@"First : %@, Last : %@",firstDayDate,lastDayDate);
```

This way you are getting First and Last Date.

Comment: I know that but i use fs calener for my app.When i change my month from fscalender then i want to get 1 & 31 date using fs calender

Comment: This is quite same that you get Date from FSCalendar or manually calculate. But from this code you get proper first and last day of month from date that you are getting from fscalendar.